# Is there any alternative for reshapeGeometry in Qgis 2.4 version

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I am splitting the polygon feature if it intersects with the line feature.
I am using reshapeGeometry() but it is nt wrking in qgis2.4. Is  there any alternative to use for this one.it is wrking perfectly fine in qgis 2.2.

```
for feature in polygonpr.getFeatures():
    geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(feature.geometry().asPolygon())
    for line in linepr.getFeatures():
        t = feature.geometry().reshapeGeometry(line.geometry().asPolyline())   
        print t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
Exception: unknown
```

I am getting the following error.

Is there any way to replace reshapeGeometry? Any solution

Comment: try storing the geometry in a variable and using that `geom = feature.geometry()` `geom.reshape...`

Comment: @NathanW I am getting the same error.